# LTE Smartphone Ubuntu-Touch like BQ Aquaris E5 LTE (not Meizu)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, internet, bq

I really like the BQ Aquaris E5 HD Ubuntu Edition, but is has no LTE. The newer version from BQ with LTE is not available with Ubuntu. I don't want to buy the Phone from Meizu.

Will there be a **version from BQ with LTE and Ubuntu Touch**?

Comment: You won't get an answer on that here. Questions about new devices are asked every week on the Community Q&A. With the result that it's bq who have to announce new devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When BQ is ready to announce new devices, they'll do so themselves.  If you haven't seen any announcement from them, then there is no public information to report.

For now if you need an LTE phone running Ubuntu, the Meizu is your only choice.